# Selenium - find_elements command, where to look?

Tags: python, selenium

I am working through a Selenium with Python book and an confused by this specific example below.  The below test runs fine:

```
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, data, unpack
from selenium import webdriver

@ddt
class SearchDDT(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create a new Chrome session
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to application home page
        self.driver.get('http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/')


    # specify test data using @ data decorator
    @data(("phones", 3), ("music", 5))
    @unpack
    def test_search(self, search_value, expected_count):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter serach keyword and submit
        # use search value argument to pass data
        self.search_field.send_keys(search_value)
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have product names displayed current on result page
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")

        # check count of products show in results
        self.assertEqual(expected_count, len(products))

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

I am confused though on this specific line:

```
# get all the anchor elements which have product names displayed current on result page
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
```

Where exactly on the page are those elements being inspected?  A shortcut to the test page in question is here:

http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=music

You can see there are 5 items returned.  My question is where is that xpath shown above found on this page that covers the 5 items and in turn makes the test pass?  I tried inspecting the individual music items themselves, that's not correct.  Basically, where should I be clicking to retrieve the 'find_elements_by_xpath' value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So they way I see it xpath is basically a shortcut to finding an element on the page and its a very useful one. So in order to find the xpath of a certain element, you will go to the console on your browser. Press `F12` or right-clicking and click inspect or `crtl + shift + i`.

Then using the top left corner you see a cursor you click on it and then select and element you want to find on the page. On the element console the select element you have selected will be highlight. Right-click and you will see copy xpath. This will directly take you to the xpath element.

Or in your case you are give `//h2[@class='product-name']/a`, so `crtl +f` to find and paste the xpath and it will show you where it pops up.